# Hive Date Time Week

Tags: datetime, hive

I want to extract date of each week's Monday for each week in hive. I can do that with Presto by using `date_trunc` function however in hive I don't have a direct function which can extract Monday Date.

My Presto code is similar to this,

```
select 
   a.abc_id
    ,cast(date_trunc('week', from_unixtime(p.xyz_date)) as timestamp) as xyz_week
from PQR
```

The output is for each id I will get Week but in the form of date format which is nothing but the date of every Monday of past weeks (user can specify how many week's he wants to assess).

I searched all the date functions of hive but is there a function which can replace `date_trunc`?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the date function : next_day(string start_date, string day_of_week)

For example:  next_day('2018-02-22', 'Mon') = '2018-02-26''

My hive version is 1.4.